# How to apply the eval function to a vector without looping?

Tags: r, vector, expression, eval

I have a problem. I try to apply the `eval` function to a vector. But the result returned is not a vector but just one value. I explain:

```
Event <- c("< 0.5")
P     <- round(runif(1:10), 4)
Vec_Ev<- parse(text=paste(P, Event))

Vec_EV
expression(0.2086 < 0.5, 0.0937 < 0.5, 0.7238 < 0.5, 0.5806 < 0.5, 
0.7616 < 0.5, 0.6743 < 0.5, 0.9124 < 0.5, 0.393 < 0.5, 0.7401 < 0.5, 
0.5601 < 0.5)
```

And now I would like to have the result of these inequations. But the result is:

```
eval(Vec_Ev)
[1] FALSE
```

instead of a vector.

Is it possible to obtain the vector result without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use eval here. Simply `P > 0.5` will work.

```
    P
    #[1] 0.3812 0.1939 0.4249 0.1729 0.4161 0.5480 0.9688 0.5409 0.7861 0.1967
    P > 0.5
    #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In general, it is recommended that you avoid resorting to eval. Use get, mget, assign instead if you really must.

Edit, for multiple events I'd suggest an approach as below. This is a quick fix but I think there might be a more elegant way to do it. I will update if I find something better.

```
library(data.table)

P  <- data.table(P1 = round(runif(1:10), 4))

# first check is for < 0.1, second is for < 0.7, third is for > 0.2
Events = c(0.1,0.7,0.2)
Compare = c('<','<','>')

for ( i in 1:length(Events))
{
P[, paste0("Event",i) := Events[i]]
if (Compare[i] == '>')
{
   P[, paste0("VecEv",i):= P1 > get( paste0('Event',i) )]
} else
{
   P[, paste0("VecEv",i):= P1 < get( paste0('Event',i) )]
}
}

 # P
        # P1 Event1 VecEv1 Event2 VecEv2 Event3 VecEv3
 # 1: 0.5328    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2  FALSE
 # 2: 0.3306    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2  FALSE
 # 3: 0.3132    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2  FALSE
 # 4: 0.1355    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2   TRUE
 # 5: 0.6571    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2  FALSE
 # 6: 0.7568    0.1   TRUE    0.7   TRUE    0.2  FALSE
 # 7: 0.9472    0.1   TRUE    0.7   TRUE    0.2  FALSE
 # 8: 0.2839    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2  FALSE
 # 9: 0.7823    0.1   TRUE    0.7   TRUE    0.2  FALSE
# 10: 0.1164    0.1   TRUE    0.7  FALSE    0.2   TRUE
```

Comment: I understand but the problem is that I have to do a loop on different events, that's why I use

Comment: I've made some changes, can you have a look?

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, please check the tick mark against the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just, in your method the results are reversed !

Comment: +1 from me. I don't think you need the `if()`. Try typing `"<"(2,3)` at the prompt.

Comment: Is "<"(2,3) the equivalent of the "2<3" expression ?